# If grade is below 75 change color to red

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help about jQuery.
How I can I make the font color of the 74 into red.
I mean once grade is below 75 font color will change to red or else green if passed.

```
$("document").ready( function(){

 //alert("working");

var passing_grade = parseInt("75");
var grade = parseInt($(".grade").val());

    if( grade < passing_grade ){
        $(".grade").css("color","#ff000");
    } else {
        $(".grade").css("color","#066d06");
}


} );
```

Comment: I tried var passing_grade = 75;
but didn't work.

Comment: this will only run on page load once and test the value at that point. Is this the wanted behavior? Post some html  also. Can't texst code without html

Comment: are you sure $(".grade").val() is not returning undefined?

Comment: open console - firebug or chrome tools (F12) - and write $(".grade").val(), see what it returns .. is .grade a textbox?

Comment: if it's not textbox then you should use .text() instead of .val()

Comment: Looks like you have a different problem. share your code in HTML and JS code in http://www.jsfiddle.net and we will help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val` method is used for getting/setting values of form elements, if the `.grade` element is not a form element, you should use `text` or `html` method, also note when `parseInt` is used, you should specify the `radix`.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".grade").css("color", function() {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10) > 75 ? "#ff0000" : "#066d06"
    })
});
```

---

For `li` elements you should use `text` method instead of `val`:

```
return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 75 ? "#ff0000" : "#066d06"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wsBBH/

Comment: It's in 
<li class="grade">74<li>
<li class="grade">80<li>
<li class="grade">70<li>

I get thos value from database

Comment: @arjay0601 So you should use `text` method.

Comment: I tried to change the .val() into .text().
all turned into green.

Comment: @arjay0601 Try this http://jsfiddle.net/wsBBH/, note that your markup is invalid.

Comment: May I know what is the 10 in the second parameter?

Comment: @arjay0601 You are welcome, that is the `radix` you can find more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with color code for red is incorrect. For red, it's `#ff0000` (It's a typo and you missed adding another zero.)

Try this code,

```
var passing_grade = parseInt("75");
var grade = parseInt($(".grade").val());

    if( grade < passing_grade ){    
        $(".grade").css("color",'#ff0000');  // <<< Change the color code HERE
    } else {
        $(".grade").css("color","#066d06");
    }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/xC89P/3/

**UPDATE:**

Try this code, You need to loop each `.grade` element and apply CSS

```
    var passing_grade = parseInt("75");

    $(".grade").each(function(){
       var grade = parseInt($(this).text());

        if( grade < passing_grade ){    
            $(this).css("color",'#ff0000');
        } else {
            $(this).css("color","#066d06");
        }
    })
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/xC89P/5/

​

Comment: didn't work all <li> tags turned into red even if it's higher than 75.

Comment: If it's not working then share your HTML and JS code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @arjay0601  If you don't post your full working code you are wasting everyone's time guessing what your problems are

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (because of your use of `.val`) that `.grade` is a text input field, then to have that field change colour each time the value changes, use this:

```
var pass = 75;

$('.grade').on('change', function() {
    var grade = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    $(this).css('color', grade < pass ? '#ff0000' : '#066d06');
});
```